# Chart.js - Can't hide PolarArea by using display:false

Tags: chart.js

I am trying to hide the numbers on the scales of a PolarArea chart in react chart.js2.
I have tried all the options below with no result.
Would love any ideas on what could work.
Thanks.

```
options:{
   ticks:{display:false}
}
```

---

```
options:{
   scale:{
     ticks:{display:false}
   }
}
```

---

```
options:{
   scale:{
     r:{
       ticks:{display:false}
     }
   }
}
```

---

```
options:{
   scale:{
      display:false
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define it in `options.scales.r.ticks`:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'polarArea',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      r: {
        ticks: {
          display: false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```